# How to set-up WebRTC with VP9 codec and lossless compression

Tags: compression, webrtc, codec, lossless, vp9

I have been trying to figure out whether or not it is possible to set up WebRTC with VP9 codec and lossless compression.

So far, I have been able to figure out, how to set VP9 in the SDP and also how to set the [coding profile](https://www.webmproject.org/vp9/profiles/) (0-3). However, my understanding is, that setting the encoder profile to index 3, does not have an impact on the compression.

I also looked at the [RTP payload specification for VP9](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-payload-vp9-09). However, the [specification for the SDP parameters](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-payload-vp9-09#page-19) only show how to set the codec and the coding profile.

So my question is, is it at all possible to set up WebRTC with VP9 lossless compression? If so, where could I set it and does it have to be set in the SDP at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this using the browser WebRTC API? I don't believe this is possible.

[WebCodecs](https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs/blob/master/explainer.md) is a proposal to give users more control over things.

You can use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) today, and then send media over a different transport maybe? I don't believe you can choose lossless though.

Comment: Thank you for the resources, they look very interesting. To your question about browser API, no, not to my understanding. We use [MixedReality-WebRTC](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC) for HoloLens, which itself uses [webrtc-uwp-sdk](https://github.com/webrtc-uwp/webrtc-uwp-sdk). And the UWP SDK itself uses Googles implementation directly as I understand. I found some information, however, that at least with VP8 there is a  "x-google-max-quantization=X" for the SDP, https://www.slideshare.net/vline/a-practical see slide 12. So it seems you are right.